# C# Saving screenshot with incrementing number

Tags: c#, save

I have created a different class which to call screenshot. Below is my code

Program.cs

```
static int i=1;  
[TestFixture(typeof(FirefoxDriver))]
[TestFixture(typeof(InternetExplorerDriver))]
[TestFixture(typeof(ChromeDriver))]
public class TestWithMultipleBrowsers<TWebDriver> where TWebDriver : IWebDriver, new()
        {
           [Test]
            public void Initialize()
            {

                PropertiesCollection.driver = new TWebDriver();
                CredentialPageObject objSignin = new CredentialPageObject();
                string pathfile = @"..\..\a.xlsx";
                string sheetName = "SignIn";
                var excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(pathfile);
                var abc = from a in excelFile.Worksheet(sheetName) select a;
                foreach (var a in abc)
                {
                    PropertiesCollection.driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(a["URL"]);
                }
                PropertiesCollection.driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                foreach (var a in abc)
                {
                    objSignin.Login(a["ID"], a["Pass"]);
                }   
                Result.screenshoot();
                FunctionPageObject objFunc = new FunctionPageObject();
         }
```

screenshot is called from Result.cs class which contains

```
  class Result
    {
        public static void screenshot() 
        {

            ITakesScreenshot screenshotDriver = PropertiesCollection.driver as ITakesScreenshot;
            Screenshot screenCapture = screenshotDriver.GetScreenshot();
            string path = @"..\..\Results\";

            string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss");
            screenCapture.SaveAsFile(@path + i + ". " + timestamp + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);


        }
    }
```

And this one is my FunctionPageObject.cs

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "Login")]
    public IWebElement clickLogin { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/select/option[2]")]
    public IWebElement Title { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "Initial")]
    public IWebElement Initial { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "FirstName")]
    public IWebElement FN { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "MiddleName")]
    public IWebElement MN { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/input[1]")]
    public IWebElement Gender { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "Hindi")]
    public IWebElement Language { get; set; }


     public void CuteEditor()
    {

        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Title.Click();
        Result.screenshot();
        Initial.EnterText("PS");
        Result.screenshot();
        FN.EnterText("Pramukh");
        Result.screenshot();
        MN.EnterText("Swami");
        Result.screenshot();
        Gender.Click();
        Result.screenshot();
        Language.Click();
        Result.screenshot();
```

Now, what I am doing here is calling Screenshot page from Result.Cs and calling it in main and FunctionPageObject class but it does create screenshot but it is not incrementing.

Actual Result: It remains 1 all the time
Expected Result: Should increment all the time.

Comment: You don't increment `i` anywhere, do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will solve the problem

```
 class Result
    {
        static int i = 1 ;
        public static void screenshot() 
        {

            ITakesScreenshot screenshotDriver = PropertiesCollection.driver as ITakesScreenshot;
            Screenshot screenCapture = screenshotDriver.GetScreenshot();
            string path = @"..\..\Results\";

            string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss");
            screenCapture.SaveAsFile(@path + i + ". " + timestamp + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            i++;

        }
    }
```